# Parse delimited string

Tags: c++, string, char

How can I get :

```
connect
100
username
example
```

from this string:

```
ngg://connect>100/username>example/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding an answer with `strtok` for the sake of diversity:

```
char str[] = "ngg://connect>100/username>example/";
char *s = strtok(str, ">/");
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
while (s = strtok(NULL, ">/"))
    tokens.push_back(std::string(s));
```

This will split the string `str` into the desired tokens (discarding the first `ngg:`, like in  the question).
Here's a [working example](http://ideone.com/639S7) of this code.

Answer (score 4):

Using `std::string::find` with arguments `"/"` and `">"` and `std::string::substr` with the found indexes.

This is a good start.

Answer (score 3):

```
ngg://connect>100/username>example/
```

If this format is fixed, then you can use `std::sscanf` as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
   char const *input = "ngg://connect>100/username>example/";
   char const *input_format = "ngg://%[^>]>%d/%[^>]>%[^/]"; 

   char connect[100], user[100], str[100]; //assuming max size is 100
   int num;

   if ( std::sscanf(input, input_format, connect, &num, user, str) != 4 )
   {
     std::cerr<<"error - number of tokens read must be equal to 4";
     return 0; 
   }  

   std::cout << connect <<std::endl;
   std::cout << num <<std::endl;
   std::cout << user <<std::endl;
   std::cout << str <<std::endl;
}
```

Output ([online demo](http://ideone.com/Md6PM)):

```
connect
100
username
example
```

Answer (score 3):

A possibility is [`boost::split()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id3184031):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::string s("ngg://connect>100/username>example/");
    boost::split(tokens, s, boost::is_any_of("/>"));

    // "connect"  == tokens[2]
    // "100"      == tokens[3]
    // "username" == tokens[4]
    // "example"  == tokens[5]

    return 0;
}
```