# Saving values from strtok function

Tags: c++, strtok

Hi i'm using the `strtok` function to split a sentence into two parts. I cant seem to figure out how to save the two separate values, the function is successfully splitting the sentence at the minute I just need to know to to store the values. Thanks

```
extern "C" UINT __stdcall GetProductName(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
{
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
UINT er = ERROR_SUCCESS;
char szProductName[MAX_PATH];
TCHAR* szValueBuf = NULL;
DWORD cchValueBuf = 0;
char * pch;
std::vector<std::string> parts;


hr = WcaInitialize(hInstall, "GetProductName");
ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to initialize");

WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "Initialized.");

UINT uiStat =  MsiGetProperty(hInstall, TEXT("ProductName"), TEXT(""), &cchValueBuf);

if (ERROR_MORE_DATA == uiStat)
{
    ++cchValueBuf; 
    szValueBuf = new TCHAR[cchValueBuf];
    if (szValueBuf)
    {
        uiStat = MsiGetProperty(hInstall, TEXT("ProductName"), szValueBuf, &cchValueBuf);

    }
}
if (ERROR_SUCCESS != uiStat)
{
    if (szValueBuf != NULL) 
        delete[] szValueBuf;
    return ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;
}

if (Orc_Create_Product_Key(szValueBuf))
    hr = S_OK;
else
    hr = ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;

pch = strtok (szValueBuf," ");
parts.push_back(pch);

  while (pch != NULL)
  {
       pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
       parts.push_back(pch);
  }


strcpy(szProductName, szValueBuf);

hr = MsiSetProperty(hInstall, "PRODUCTNAME",  szProductName);
ExitOnFailure(hr, "failed to set PRODUCTNAME");

LExit:
er = SUCCEEDED(hr) ? ERROR_SUCCESS : ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;
return WcaFinalize(er);
 }
```

As you can see the first value will be `szProductName` but I need to get the second value also.

Comment: Ah! Back out now. Use `std::string`.

Comment: Using `strtok` to find the first space is kind of silly. You're writing C++ code, use a sensible string class.

Comment: `boost::split()` is one alternative option (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273989/parse-delimited-string/11274085#11274085 for example use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you store it in a vector?

```
std::vector<std::string> parts;
pch = strtok (szValueBuf," ");
parts.push_back(pch);

while (pch != NULL)
{
   pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
   parts.push_back(pch);
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but got this error `error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage`..any ideas?

Comment: then you are doing something which you don't show us. Please provide more info. Is there something declared with C linkage (e.g. `extern "C"`)? Is this .cpp or .c file (your question is tagged as `c++`)?

Comment: Yes the function has `Extern "C"` in it as I am using C++ Custom action Project. Sorry should have stated that. It is a .cpp file.:)

Comment: this doesn't preclude using the vector inside the function. do you also return the vector from the function?

Comment: Even if you return a `vector` from `extern "C"` function, there shouldn't be that message. Are you defining any template classes/methods yourself?

Comment: the function is fine. to which line does the compiler error point?

Comment: Not as far as I am aware, i'm very new to c++, I have been given some code that I have to enhance so that it interacts with my MSI. It does not point to a specific line, when I click on the error it brings up the xstddef file.

Comment: compiler errors (e.g. `error C2894`) always point to some code reference, including the line. Don't use Errors window, use Output window to see the details and exactly where it points to. when you remove the vector parts then it builds?

Comment: This is the exact line `1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstddef(78): error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage` Yes it builds fine with the vector parts removed..:)

Comment: what are the lines around this one - does any of them point to code within your function. regarding `C++ Custom action Project` what exactly do you mean by that? are there any special settings for this file?